# IIS 7.0 (IIS Express) Setup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, iis-express

Given the following setup:

```
Website: "Web"
Modules: Web/Module1, Web/Module2/, ...
URL: http://web
```

we have a business requirement to go from

http://web

to

http://web/Snapshot1

http://web/Snapshot2

...

http://web/Snapshotn

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to go about this, with simply modifying routconfig or similar (please note, there will be a brand new copy of "web" and "modules" per snapshot.

I tried Setting the "project Url" to "http://Web/Snapshot1" and add a RouteConfig.cs entry for "Snapshot1"

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Snapshot1",
                url: "Snapshot1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

This throws off all the js, stylesheet, and images relative paths; so I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Also to make life more interesting, due to company policies, we do not have admin privileges anywhere (including dev boxes); so playing with IIS is not an option (unless you know of a way?); i'm limited to IIS Express

**Update**

As per the suggestion, I updated my IIS Express config;
Unfortunately, this following setup causes a URL rewrite where the snapshot name is removed

```
    <site name="Web-Site" id="1">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="H:\Data\My Documents\My Web Sites\Web-Site" />
        </application>
        <application path="/snapshot1" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\abc\def\Web" />
        </application>
        <application path="/snapshot1/WebShell" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\abc\def\Web\Modules\Shared\WebShell" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:2222:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
```

Comment: Why not create each "Snapshot" as an application of the "Web" website? You can give each their own Application Pool too. The routes would automatically pick up the virtual path - you wouldn't need to configure it as part of the routes.

Comment: I'd love too... i'm not sure how I can do that in IIS Express though :( If only I had access to IIS .... do you know how I can configure webapps in iis express?

Comment: You can access the IIS Express configuration file in `C:\users\{username}\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`. From there, find your website entry, and then lookup the configuration options. I think it's like `<application path="/your-path" applicationPool="yourApplicationPool"><virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\path-to-your-app" /></application>`

Comment: I updated my question to include the changes I made to my IIS Express settings...the URL doesn't keep the snapshot name (I do have a routeConfig rule for turning Webshell/{controller}/{action}/Index; i'm not sure if that's what's causing the issue

Comment: Leave the application parts out of your routes. That get appended automatically by the MVC routing framework. What is this `routeConfig` rule?

Comment: hey btw, I just wanted to say, thanks for your help; your suggestion completely resolved my issue; it would've been 100 times easier if I had access to IIS; but configuring IIS express the way you suggested helped massively. thanks again :)

Comment: Cool. You should post what you ended up doing, and accept your solution as the answer! Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Crush here was very helpful;
Here's what I did so I can resolve my URL requirements (would've been super simple to test this with good old IIS; oh well.... as long as it can be done I guess):

```
http://website/Prod
http://website/snapshot1
http://website/snapshot2
http://website/dev
http://website/staging
```

underneath each of the above I  would have different modules deployed (however, the root of the URL is not "Website", rather it's "Website/{somename}/modules";

So something like:

```
http://website/Prod/Members
http://website/Prod/Loans
http://website/Prod/Blogs
http://website/Prod/Documents
http://website/Prod/Media

http://website/snapshot1/Members
http://website/snapshot1/Loans
http://website/snapshot1/Documents
http://website/snapshot1/Media

http://website/snapshot2/Members
http://website/snapshot2/Loans
http://website/snapshot2/Media
```

In IIS - Express config file (applicationhost.config), I created the following and everything magically happened to work:

```
    <site name="website-name-or-whatever-the-heck-you-want-it-2b" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="path to some snapshot selector" />
        </application>
        <application path="/snapshot1/Members" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\...\path to members" />
        </application>
        <application path="/snapshot1/Loans" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\...\path to Loans" />
        </application>
        <application path="/snapshot1/Blogs" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\...\path to Blogs" />
        </application>
        <application path="/snapshot1/Documents" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\...\path to Documents" />
        </application>
        <application path="/snapshot1/Media" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath=Media />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5260:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
```